# Flutuar metade da lista do Menu Dropdown para outra posição

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, dropdown

Como fazer para na sexta célula do *Menu Dropdown* flutuar para esquerda como no exemplo da imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Tentei sem sucesso algo como:

```
<style>
    #main-navigation-2 .dropdown-menu :nth-child(6),
    #main-navigation-2 .dropdown-menu :nth-child(7),
    #main-navigation-2 .dropdown-menu :nth-child(8),
    #main-navigation-2 .dropdown-menu :nth-child(9),
    #main-navigation-2 .dropdown-menu :nth-child(10)
    {
    right:0;
    }
</style>
```

Código do Menu

```
<div id="main-navigation-2" class="hidden-xs col-sm-12 col-md-12">
   <!-- <div class="container"> -->
   <nav class="navbar-main-navigation mb-xs-10" role="navigation">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li class="dropdown"> 
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="0"> 
            <img class="img-responsive thumb-0" src="assets/images/menu-icones-black/image.jpg" /><p>Banheiro</p></a>  
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="0"> 
            <img class="img-responsive thumb-0" src="assets/images/menu-icones-black/image.jpg" /><p>Cozinha</p></a>  
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="0"> 
            <img class="img-responsive thumb-0" src="assets/images/menu-icones-black/image.jpg" /><p>Infantil</p></a>  
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="0"> 
            <img class="img-responsive thumb-0" src="assets/images/menu-icones-black/image.jpg" /><p>Jarras & Copos</p></a>  
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="0"> 
            <img class="img-responsive thumb-0" src="assets/images/menu-icones-black/image.jpg" /><p>Limpeza</p></a>  
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="0"> 
            <img class="img-responsive thumb-0" src="assets/images/menu-icones-black/image.jpg" /><p>Mesa</p></a>  
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="0"> 
            <img class="img-responsive thumb-0" src="assets/images/menu-icones-black/image.jpg" /><p>Microondas</p></a>  
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="0"> 
            <img class="img-responsive thumb-0" src="assets/images/menu-icones-black/image.jpg" /><p>Organização</p></a>  
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="0"> 
            <img class="img-responsive thumb-0" src="assets/images/menu-icones-black/image.jpg" /><p>Potes</p></a>  
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="0"> 
            <img class="img-responsive thumb-0" src="assets/images/menu-icones-black/image.jpg" /><p>Tábuas</p></a>  

            <ul class="dropdown-menu menu-right">
               <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
               <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
               <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
               <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
               <br><span class="pull-right">+ PRODUTOS</span>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </nav><!-- .navbar-collapse -->
   <!-- </div> --> <!-- #container-->
</div><!-- #main-navigation -->
```

Comment: Denis posso te dar uma dica para te facilitar a vida? Se não for problema coloque a Barra Verde com 100% de Width e alinha os itens no Centro. Assim vai te dar menos dor de cabeça para deixar tudo Responsivo sem precisar de JS etc...

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, mas pretendo ir com ele até a screen-tablet só !

Comment: Vc reparou que vc escreveu "rihgt:0;" errado? Deveria ser **RIGHT**, no seu código está escrito errado! []´s

Comment: Coloque o código completo do menu para que possamos analisar.

Comment: Hugocsl eu vi obrigado mas esse não funfa mesmo !

Comment: dvd eu atualizei o código acho que agora da pra entender

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagino que cada `<li>` seja um botão do menu, onde também está incluído um `<ul>` que é o menu *dropdown* do respectivo botão.

Nisso, o seletor correto dos menus, de 6 a 10, seria:

```
#main-navigation-2 nav ul li.dropdown:nth-child(6) ul,
#main-navigation-2 nav ul li.dropdown:nth-child(7) ul,
#main-navigation-2 nav ul li.dropdown:nth-child(8) ul,
#main-navigation-2 nav ul li.dropdown:nth-child(9) ul,
#main-navigation-2 nav ul li.dropdown:nth-child(10) ul
{
   right: 0;
   left: auto;
}
```

Ou simplesmente crie um `class` e adicione nos elementos:

```
ul.menu_direita{
   right: 0;
   left: auto;
}
```

**Teste (execute em tela cheia):**

```css
ul.menu_direita{
   right: 0;
   left: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="main-navigation-2" class="hidden-xs col-sm-12 col-md-12">
   <!--<div class="container">-->
      <nav class="navbar-main-navigation mb-xs-10" role="navigation">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown"> 
               <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="0"> 
               <img class="img-responsive thumb-0" src="assets/images/menu-icones-black/image.jpg" /><p>Banheiro</p></a>  
               <ul class="dropdown-menu menu-right">
                  <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
                  <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
                  <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
                  <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
                  <br><span class="pull-right">+ PRODUTOS</span>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"> 
               <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="0"> 
               <img class="img-responsive thumb-0" src="assets/images/menu-icones-black/image.jpg" /><p>Cozinha</p></a>  
               <ul class="dropdown-menu menu-right">
                  <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
                  <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
                  <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
                  <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
                  <br><span class="pull-right">+ PRODUTOS</span>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"> 
               <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="0"> 
               <img class="img-responsive thumb-0" src="assets/images/menu-icones-black/image.jpg" /><p>Infantil</p></a>  
               <ul class="dropdown-menu menu-right">
                  <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
                  <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
                  <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
                  <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
                  <br><span class="pull-right">+ PRODUTOS</span>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"> 
               <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="0"> 
               <img class="img-responsive thumb-0" src="assets/images/menu-icones-black/image.jpg" /><p>Jarras & Copos</p></a>  
               <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" style="float: right;">
                  <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
                  <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
                  <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
                  <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
                  <br><span class="pull-right">+ PRODUTOS</span>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"> 
               <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="0"> 
               <img class="img-responsive thumb-0" src="assets/images/menu-icones-black/image.jpg" /><p>Limpeza</p></a>  
               <ul class="dropdown-menu menu-right">
                  <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
                  <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
                  <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
                  <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
                  <br><span class="pull-right">+ PRODUTOS</span>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"> 
               <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="0"> 
               <img class="img-responsive thumb-0" src="assets/images/menu-icones-black/image.jpg" /><p>Mesa</p></a>  
               <ul class="dropdown-menu menu-right menu_direita">
                  <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
                  <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
                  <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
                  <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
                  <br><span class="pull-right">+ PRODUTOS</span>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"> 
               <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="0"> 
               <img class="img-responsive thumb-0" src="assets/images/menu-icones-black/image.jpg" /><p>Microondas</p></a>  
               <ul class="dropdown-menu menu-right menu_direita">
                  <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
                  <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
                  <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
                  <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
                  <br><span class="pull-right">+ PRODUTOS</span>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"> 
               <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="0"> 
               <img class="img-responsive thumb-0" src="assets/images/menu-icones-black/image.jpg" /><p>Organização</p></a>  
               <ul class="dropdown-menu menu-right menu_direita">
                  <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
                  <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
                  <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
                  <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
                  <br><span class="pull-right">+ PRODUTOS</span>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"> 
               <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="0"> 
               <img class="img-responsive thumb-0" src="assets/images/menu-icones-black/image.jpg" /><p>Potes</p></a>  
               <ul class="dropdown-menu menu-right menu_direita">
                  <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
                  <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
                  <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
                  <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
                  <br><span class="pull-right">+ PRODUTOS</span>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"> 
               <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="0"> 
               <img class="img-responsive thumb-0" src="assets/images/menu-icones-black/image.jpg" /><p>Tábuas</p></a>  
               <ul class="dropdown-menu menu-right menu_direita">
                  <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
                  <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
                  <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
                  <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
                  <br><span class="pull-right">+ PRODUTOS</span>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </nav><!-- .navbar-collapse -->
   <!--</div>-->
</div><!-- #main-navigation -->
```

Comment: Exatamente assim que precisava obrigado a todos !

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar a classe [`.dropdown-menu-right`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#dropdowns-alignment) para alterar o alinhamento do dropdown

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- <div id="main-navigation-2" class="hidden-xs col-sm-12 col-md-12"> -->
<div id="main-navigation-2">
  <nav class="navbar-main-navigation mb-xs-10" role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="dropdown"> 
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="0">
          <img class="img-responsive thumb-0" src="assets/images/menu-icones-black/image.jpg" />
          <p>Item 1</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown"> 
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="0">
          <img class="img-responsive thumb-0" src="assets/images/menu-icones-black/image.jpg" />
          <p>Item 2</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="0">
          <img class="img-responsive thumb-0" src="assets/images/menu-icones-black/image.jpg" />
          <p>Algo</p>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
          <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
          <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
          <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href=""><img class="thumb" src="assets/Imagens/foto-1-12.jpg" /></a></li>
          <br><span class="pull-right">+ PRODUTOS</span>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav><!-- .navbar-collapse -->
</div><!-- #main-navigation -->
```

Comment: Eu adicionei a classe `dropdown-menu-right` no elemento do dropdown para alterar o alinhamento do menu quando ele está aberto como indicado na documentação do bootstrap. Se você executar o código e clicar em Página toda verá que o dropdown está alinhado a direita como solicitado.

Comment: Verdade. Eu não notei que tinha que clicar no menu rs..

Answer (score 1):

Fiz algo parecido, isso já, só que determinava a direção do menu de acordo com o tamanho da tela, o código era mais ou menos como no exemplo, o menu não era com bootstrap e nem responsivo, fiz o exemplo com as classes do bootstrap, espero que ajude ...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div id="main-navigation-2">
  <nav class="navbar-main-navigation mb-xs-10" role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >
          Item 1
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >
          Item 2
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href="">item-2.1</a></li>
          <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href="">item-2.2</a></li>
          <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href="">item-2.3</a></li>
          <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href="">item-2.4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >
          Item 3
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href="">item-3.1</a></li>
          <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href="">item-3.2</a></li>
          <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href="">item-3.3</a></li>
          <li><a class="imagem-horizontal" href="">item-3.4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav><!-- .navbar-collapse -->
</div><!-- #main-navigation -->
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>

function normalizarDirecaoSubmenu() {
 var tela = $(window).width();
 var limiteMenu = 650; //tamanho da tela
 $('.dropdown').each(function(index, el) {
  var $el = $(el),
   offset = $el.offset();
   direcao = (tela - offset.left) < limiteMenu ? 'dropdown-menu-left' : 'dropdown-menu-right';
  $el.find('.dropdown-menu').addClass(direcao);
 });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 normalizarDirecaoSubmenu();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @denis, aqui no site talvez não consiga visualizar o funcionamento correto mas, vc pode salvar o código local e testar com tamanhos de telas diferentes.

Comment: eu testei o seu aparentemente funciona com js, mas eu queria uma solução no CSS usando nth-child ou com js mesmo mas usando a 5ª TAG <li class="dropdown"> como limitador fazendo a mudança  a partir de MESA. Com CSS e nth-child normalmente eu faço isso  e nesse caso não tá dando certo pois deve haver algum conflito no CSS.. resolvi  temporariamente usando dois menus vou aguardar mais respostas enquanto faço um teste em uma página limpa pra confirmar depois o porque o nth-child não quer funcionar

Comment: Blz, soluções apenas com CSS são bem mais legais ...